# Returning vector from template function

Tags: c++, templates

Hoping for some clarification here. The code below executes fine, but when I uncomment that else statement a compilation error occurs. It's because in `main` I'm specifying a type `int` event though there's the possibility of type `string`. I've simplified my actual code to what's below to narrow down on the problem, what can I do to make it so that vector `data` in `main` can be of whatever type getNextLineOfData returns?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template< typename T>
std::vector<T> getNextLineOfData(bool someBoolean)
    {
        std::vector<T> data;
        if (someBoolean)
        {
            data.push_back(1);
            data.push_back(2);
            data.push_back(3);
        }
        /*
        else
        {
            data.push_back("1");
            data.push_back("2");
            data.push_back("3");
        }
        */
return data;
    };

int main()
{
vector<int> data = getNextLineOfData<int>(true);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::vector` can only contain one type at a time. You can't push both `string`s and `int`s into it.

Comment: I guess you cannot do such a thing because some type may not have means to be converted from `int`. You can use template specialization for supporting some specific types you choose.

Comment: As others have noted you can't mix datatypes in an array. What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to be able to set vector data, in main, to whatever is returned from getNextLineOfData. I'm trying to have a simple line like data = whatever is returned from that function.

Comment: @LBaelish If you use the @ tag I will be notified when you write. That part I understand, but "next line" usually signifies char-data; what is the reason you have to mix `int` and `string`?

Comment: @pingul The function is involved in reading data from a file. After a line of data is read, it could contain integers or strings. The code I provided is not the code in question, just a simplified example showing the same problem.  I need to be able to return a vector containing the strings, or the integers whichever was present in that line of the file

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing compile time operations with runtime operations in your code snippet. When you template the function `getNextLineOfData` and instantiate it with `getNextLineOfData<int>`, the compiler goes ahead and generates a function that returns a vector for you. The if statement however is only evaluated at run time. So when the compiler tries to build your code it sees that you are adding both `1` and `"1"` to your `vector<int>` container based on the conditional. This is not allowed. 
You could solve your problem with template specialization.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> getNextLineOfData() {
  // default
}

template<>
std::vector<int> getNextLineOfData()
    {
        std::vector<int> data;

            data.push_back(1);
            data.push_back(2);
            data.push_back(3);

            return data;
    };

template<>
std::vector<std::string> getNextLineOfData()
    {
        std::vector<std::string> data;

            data.push_back("1");
            data.push_back("2");
            data.push_back("3");

            return data;
    };
int main()
{
    vector<int> data = getNextLineOfData<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: As @BobTFish points out, it might be better to overload the function rather than template specialize it. The solution above solves the problem the way you had it initially set up.

Comment: Firstly, you need to declare the template before you specialise it, and secondly, [*Why Not Specialize Function Templates?*](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Reading from extra information in comments, I would suggest something like:

```
void getNextLine(std::vector<std::string>& output)
{
    output.push_back("string data as you please");
}

void getNextLine(std::vector<int>& output)
{
    output.push_back(1);
}

bool nextLineIsIntData()
{
    // somehow determine if the coming data is strings or ints
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> stringData;
    std::vector<int> intData;
    if (nextLineIsIntData())
        getNextLine(intData);
    else 
        getNextLine(stringData);
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well what you are doing is simply illegal. When *you* look at the `if-else` statement you say, well if some condition is true than *this* will execute but *this* won't, so it stands too reason that the compiler will ignore the part that is not executed. This is flat out wrong. What you need to do, which is layed out in previous answers is too overload or specialize the function for the different data types.

I should also mention that what you are *trying* to do is bad style. You are essentially relying on the user too pass the correct `bool` value, which influences the types you `push_back()` into the vector. Why do this when you have the power of template pattern matching at your disposal which completely removes the need to rely on correct user input.

*In this case and any similar ones you come across it's much better to let the compiler decide*